# Configuration .htaccess in SLIM Framework

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, slim

How do I adjust the `.htaccess` file for my slim-framework?

I have this folders/files:

- `/src/slim.php`
- `/public/.htaccess`

My URL points to the "public" directory. And I want to create a virtual "folder" so if I call `http://example.com/api/...` it should open my slim application in the `src` folder.

I have created this `.htaccess` file, but it doesn't work.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^api ../src/slim.php
```

This error message appears:
[image: Error message slim framework]

Comment: What is your document root?

Comment: The document root is "htdocs/project/src". I work with XAMPP.

Comment: Is that the same `/src` as in `/src/slim.php`?! But I assume not. Are both `/src/slim.php` and `/public/.htaccess` inside your document root?

Comment: "it doesn't work." - What happens exactly? Do you get an error? Nothing?

Answer (score 0):

> My URL points to the "public" directory.
>   :
>   The document root is "htdocs/project/src".

It's not clear how your "URL points to the `public` directory", when your document root appears to point elsewhere? Do you have another `.htaccess` file in the document root perhaps?

Anyway, it looks like you might be trying to rewrite to a file that is outside the document root? That is not possible using mod_rewrite in a `.htaccess` context. The server will likely respond with a `400 Bad Request`.

Comment: The .htaccess file in the public directory is the only file i have created on the whole webspace.